# PHP json encode error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having the following error on an HTML page.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: page URL Here
>   Unexpected token ;

This is the code (variables are defined elsewhere and do exist.

```
<script>
    statesDropDown = <?php echo json_encode($this->states);?>;
    programIdsDropDown = <?php echo json_encode($this->programIdsData);?>;
</script>
```

This is the results of the above on the page

```
<script>
    statesDropDown = [{"id":"1","code":"AL","name":"Alabama"},{"id":"2","code":"AK","name":"Alaska"},{"id":"3","code":"AZ","name":"Arizona"},{"id":"4","code":"AR","name":"Arkansas"},{"id":"5","code":"CA","name":"California"},{"id":"6","code":"CO","name":"Colorado"},{"id":"7","code":"CT","name":"Connecticut"},{"id":"8","code":"DE","name":"Delaware"},{"id":"9","code":"FL","name":"Florida"},{"id":"10","code":"GA","name":"Georgia"},{"id":"11","code":"HI","name":"Hawaii"},{"id":"12","code":"ID","name":"Idaho"},{"id":"13","code":"IL","name":"Illinois"},{"id":"14","code":"IN","name":"Indiana"},{"id":"15","code":"IA","name":"Iowa"},{"id":"16","code":"KS","name":"Kansas"},{"id":"17","code":"KY","name":"Kentucky"},{"id":"18","code":"LA","name":"Louisiana"},{"id":"19","code":"ME","name":"Maine"},{"id":"20","code":"MD","name":"Maryland"},{"id":"21","code":"MA","name":"Massachusetts"},{"id":"22","code":"MI","name":"Michigan"},{"id":"23","code":"MN","name":"Minnesota"},{"id":"24","code":"MS","name":"Mississippi"},{"id":"25","code":"MO","name":"Missouri"},{"id":"26","code":"MT","name":"Montana"},{"id":"27","code":"NE","name":"Nebraska"},{"id":"28","code":"NV","name":"Nevada"},{"id":"29","code":"NH","name":"New Hampshire"},{"id":"30","code":"NJ","name":"New Jersey"},{"id":"31","code":"NM","name":"New Mexico"},{"id":"32","code":"NY","name":"New York"},{"id":"33","code":"NC","name":"North Carolina"},{"id":"34","code":"ND","name":"North Dakota"},{"id":"35","code":"OH","name":"Ohio"},{"id":"36","code":"OK","name":"Oklahoma"},{"id":"37","code":"OR","name":"Oregon"},{"id":"38","code":"PA","name":"Pennsylvania"},{"id":"39","code":"RI","name":"Rhode Island"},{"id":"40","code":"SC","name":"South Carolina"},{"id":"41","code":"SD","name":"South Dakota"},{"id":"42","code":"TN","name":"Tennessee"},{"id":"43","code":"TX","name":"Texas"},{"id":"44","code":"UT","name":"Utah"},{"id":"45","code":"VT","name":"Vermont"},{"id":"46","code":"VA","name":"Virginia"},{"id":"47","code":"WA","name":"Washington"},{"id":"48","code":"WV","name":"West Virginia"},{"id":"49","code":"WI","name":"Wisconsin"},{"id":"50","code":"WY","name":"Wyoming"}];
    programIdsDropDown = ;
</script>
```

I've removed the encode and confirm that I get a cannot convert array to string error.  Why is this returning blank here and causing the before mentioned error?

This is code that was moved from a 2012 Windows Server to a 2008 Windows Server and ran completely fine in 2012.  Are there any known issues with this JS call in 2008?  This is used within AngularJS but at this point of error is independent of the AngularJS so is just basic JS/PHP.

Many thanks.

Comment: `$this->programIdsData` is empty.  Check it and if empty do something else.

Comment: Do you want those vars to contain the actual object or the JSON string?

Comment: The JSON object because of how the AngularJS handles it. Guillaume STLR found the solution for me and will be accepting it as soon as the timer passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `json_encode` returns an empty string, it's maybe due to the fact that the datas contain non ASCII caracters. Try to encode them in utf-8 like this :

```
<script>
    statesDropDown = <?php echo json_encode($this->states);?>;
    programIdsDropDown = <?php echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $this->programIdsData));?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you much.  That was the problem.  Any idea why that would work in one location and not the other?

Comment: Could you give me the output generated please ? I will tell you why ;-)

Comment: It's about 300 values I'm assuming there was a character that was unfriendly with utf8 being returned.  It's just odd that it changed between the two environments.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to first avoid `echo` the `json_encode` return value. First assign it to a php variable and check if it is an empty string, then `echo '[]'`